# How to manage Juju's LXC containers using virsh?

Tags: virtualization, juju, lxc

I use the lxc driver for juju and I have created a local environment; actually the well-known Wordpress from https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started.

I then tried

```
export VIRSH_DEFAULT_URI=lxc:///
virsh list
```

and got an empty list of containers.

Where are the lxc containers which Juju created for me?

Answer (score 2):

juju doesn't use libvirt to manage lxc containers at all.  Juju's libvirt dep was just to use the default libvirt networking.

The libvirt dep has recently been removed from juju trunk to favor using the (quite similar) default networking provided by the 12.04 lxc packages.

Answer (score 0):

They should be in the same place as all the other constainers, namely, `/var/lib/lcx` Did you manage to list them using `lxc-ls`?
If you have done so, you still have to notify the driver about your containers using an XML file: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-libvirt